# iPhone safari browser ajax undefined error - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iphone-4

I made a mobile website using jquery and tested it on various devices (Android, BlackBerry and iPhone). I have a issue that happens strictly on iPhone 4. No other phone has this issue. When I use the back button (which is powered through the jquery mobile back button functionality), it shows "undefined" after executing the back function. I can see the page I previously browsed, but after that it automatically shows "undefined" in few seconds. Can anyone tell me why this happens on only iPhone 4. No other iPhone displays this error. Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you in anticipation. Have a great day ahead.

Code Sample -1

```
<a class='backbtn' data-corners="false" data-ajax='false' data-role='button' data-inline="true" data-rel='back'>Back</a>

if($this->params['controller']=='class1' && $this->params['action'] == 'index' ){
                                echo $html->link(null,
                                                            array('controller' => 'class1',
                                                                    'action' => 'options'),
                                                            array('class' => 'menuclass1',
                                                                    'data-corners' => "false",
                                                                    'data-role' => 'button',
                                                                    'data-ajax' => "false",
                                                                    'data-inline' => "true"));
                     }
```

Code Sample -2

```
<a class='backbtn' data-corners="false" data-ajax='false' data-role='button' data-inline="true" data-rel='back'>Back</a>
                     <?php }?>
            </div>
            <div class='ui-block-b'>
                     <?php if($this->params['controller']!='class3' && $this->params['controller']!='class2'){?>
                             <?php if($this->params['action']=='inquiry'){
                                     echo $html->link(null,
                                                        array('controller' => 'class5',
                                                                'action' => 'options'),
                                                        array('class' => 'menushort',
                                                                'data-corners' => "false",
                                                                'data-role' => 'button',
                                                                'data-ajax' => "false",
                                                                'data-inline' => "true"));
                                    ?>

                               <?php    
                                }
                         ?>
```

Regards,
BG

Comment: Example code or link would help

Comment: Errors? PHP and/or JavaScript? HArd to tell what's going on with your example code. Also is there any output from mobile safari debug console?

Comment: There is no specific error. Once I use the back button, it goes to the previous page and then prints "undefined". I have kept 'data-ajax' => "false" and still that happens. And this happens only on iPhone 4. Not in any other version of iPhone. Let me check the mobile safari debug console. I am using CakePhp and jquery mobile. This is the code from the "view" of a controller. Hence, you might see php and jquery all together with html tags.

Regards, BG

Comment: Nothing in debug console as well. It shows no error. Regards, BG